# Cannot find SQL Server CE 4.0 in Data Source

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

I have both SQL Server CE 3.5 and 4.0 installed. In VS2010 WPF, when I add new connection and want to create a database with SQL Server CE 4.0, I only see Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5, but not 4.0.

Why?

This is a WPF desktop application, not a Web Project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to update your Visual Studio 2010 to SP1 (from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=75568aa6-8107-475d-948a-ef22627e57a5)) to do so. Or you can try to use [this](http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/) tool.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into same problem lately when trying to add rdlc reports to my WPF application, and unfortunately you cannot add a compact 4.0 dataset to WPF project.

My workaround was to -

1. Add an empty web application that I then added my dataset and reports.
2. I then copied the rdlc's straight into my wpf project and added the dataset to a dal library to bind the data to the reports. (when creating the empty web application you can save time by  giving it the same namespace as your dal library.

I know that this is a hack but it got me out of a tight spot.

Answer (score 1):

Using SQLCE40 in VS2010 is going to be little bit of a challenge.

When you update to SP1 you will find that when go to "add" a local db to your project there is a selection for "SQL Server Compact 4.0 Local Database".

If you create a SQLCE40 local database and then try to "Add" "Existing Item..." to your project and select your existing SQLCE40 local database you will get a warning about it not being supported in the project type if it is not of a web project type.

Erik's [SQL Server Compact Toolbox](//http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/) makes the challenge using SQLCE40 in VS2010SP1 much more manageable, especially if you're trying to use it using a non-web project type.